# Stuck trying to prove an integral inequality.

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $f$ be a continuously differentiable function in $[a,b]$. Also, $f(a)=0$.
I need to prove that:
$$\int_a^b|f(t)|dt \le (b-a)\int_a^b|f'(t)|dt$$

I tried:

We know that $f$ is differentiable, so it has a max($M$) and min($m$) in the area $[a,b]$.
 Let K=max{M, -m}.
$$\int_a^b|f(t)|dt \le K(b-a) $$
Also:
$$ (b-a)\int_a^b|f'(t)|dt \ge  (b-a)|\int_a^b f'(t)dt  | \ge (b-a)|f(b)|$$
So if we prove that $K \le |f(b)|$ which means, $K=|f(b)|$, we're done. But I feel like we shouldn't prove that, because that's not even true. Directions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $f(a) = 0$, we see $$\lvert f(x) \rvert = \left \lvert \int_a^x f'(t) dt \right \rvert \le \int_a^x \lvert f'(t) \rvert dt.$$ Now integrating from $x=a$ to $x=b$ gives $$\int_a^b \lvert f(x) \rvert dx \le \int_a^b \int^x_a \lvert f'(t) \rvert dt dx.$$ Switching the order of integration in the latter gives $$\int_a^b \lvert f(x) \rvert dx \le \int^b_a \int_t^b \lvert f'(t) \rvert dx dt = \int_a^b (b-t) \lvert f'(t) \rvert dt.$$ But over the range of integration we have $(b-t) \le (b-a)$, so $$\int^b_a \lvert f(x) \rvert dx \le (b-a) \int^b_a \lvert f'(t) \rvert dt$$ which is the desired conclusion.

Comment: You are a genius!

Comment: Can you elaborate on why $\int_a^b \lvert f(x) \rvert dx \le \int^b_a \int_t^b \lvert f'(t) \rvert dx dt$ is true? Why $\int_t^b \lvert f'(t) \rvert dx dt = \int_a^x \lvert f'(t) \rvert dx dt$?

Comment: It's the double integrals that are equal. Draw a picture to see why: if we draw a square in the $x-t$ with $x$ on the $x$-axis and $t$ on the $y$-axis then the integral $\int_a^b \int_a^x \cdots dt dx$ corresponds to integrating the triangle constituting the lower right half of the square (below the diagonal $t= x$). It is equivalent to integrate in $x$ first from $x=t$ to $x=b$ and then integrate in $t$. These integrals cover the same area and swapping the order is justified bu Fubini's theorem.

Comment: In symbols: \begin{equation} (1) \hspace{0.5cm} a \le t \le x \text{ and } a \le x \le b\end{equation}  is equivalent to \begin{equation} (2)\hspace{0.5cm} t \le x \le b \text{ and } a \le t \le b.\end{equation} The first double integral above uses $(1)$ and when we 'swap the order of integration' we are switching to $(2)$.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks :)